# Alter HTML Header on each Wordpress Page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

At my website, www.TattiniBoots.com, you can see that there is a large elegant header at the top. This header remains on all pages.

For example, let's use this page: https://www.tattiniboots.com/our-company/. When you visit that page, and then begin to scroll; it is very jumpy. As the header changes to the sticky header it makes the website skip

For this reason I would like to have just a regular default header style on ALL pages EXCEPT the home page

```
<div class="col-md-12 topnav-left centar"> is the header class for the LARGE header

<div class="col-md-3 topnav-left centar"> is the header class for the SMALL header
```

I have tried to create a custom.php header for the home page and call it in my header file. However this seems to only add 2 white bars at the top of my page with no avail

Comment: "*[L]et's use this page...*" - no, let's not; instead please provide the "*[mcve]*" code that reproduces your problem in this question, where it's easily available to those trying to help you, and where it can remain for the future for other visitors with similar problems. That way, when you fix your problem, it doesn't invalidate the question.

Comment: <?php 
if(is_page(home)) {
 get_header('header-home');
}
else {
 get_header();
}
 wp_head();
?>

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue. I simply do not how to call my home page in Wordpress php